# Какая приоритетность селекторов в CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

1. Свойства прямо в HTML дереве
2. ID
3. Классы
4. Задавать напрямую тегам.

Правильно? Может что то пропустил?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/137588/
https://webref.ru/css/selector
https://yoksel.github.io/css-selectors/
https://yoksel.github.io/css-selectors-part2/
https://yoksel.github.io/pages/css-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

В целом верно. Но, ещё есть такая нехорошая вещь как `!important`, она идёт уровнем `0` в данном списке.

Comment: А можно ещё прямо инлайнить CSS в HTML с !important =) Что б контрольный!